# Facebook Pixel: The product parameter IDs provided cannot be found in the catalog

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-pixel

For some reason, my facebook pixel product ids are not in sync with my catalog and I have no idea why it's not working.

Here is the Facebook pixel extension output for content id "700076955"
[image]

When I go to my catalog and do a search I have the following available:

[image]

And I have my data sources connected to my pixel in the catalog as shown here:

[image]

Any ideas on what I am missing?  How do I get this connected properly?

Answer (score 0):

content_type needed to be "hotel"